# Google Maps Directions url error when adding multiple waypoints

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I am trying to add multiple waypoints to my google directions request.

When I add a single waypoint like

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&origin=51.507679,-0.125004&waypoints=51.524151,-0.123174&destination=51.495777,-0.108642&mode=walking`

it works fine but when I try to add multiple waypoints like

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&origin=51.606502,0.527309&waypoints=51.507679,-0.125004|51.524151,-0.123174&destination=51.495777,-0.108642&mode=walking
```

i receive a 'unsupported URL' error.  What is the correct way to add multiple waypoints? Thanks

Comment: G-Man-IOS I had a same problem that what you have.I give you the solution on Monday.

Comment: Is it OK for you?

Comment: Yes that would be great thanks

Comment: Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: For sure tomorrow I post my answer.As I have some work I could not answer.

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple, Just replace '|' with '%7C'

Your updated url will be :

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&origin=51.606502,0.527309&waypoints=51.507679,-0.125004%7C51.524151,-0.123174&destination=51.495777,-0.108642&mode=walking`

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

I give you the solution step by step

**First we should get the** [Google Map SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start)

**Drag the following bundles into your project (when prompted, select Copy items if needed):**

```
Subspecs/Base/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework
Subspecs/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework
Subspecs/Maps/Frameworks/GoogleMapsCore.framework
```

**Right-click GoogleMaps.framework in your project, and select Show In Finder.**

**Drag the GoogleMaps.bundle from the Resources folder into your project. When prompted, ensure Copy items into destination group's folder is not selected.**

**Select your project from the Project Navigator, and choose your application's target.**

**Open the Build Phases tab, and within Link Binary with Libraries, add the following frameworks:**

```
GoogleMapsBase.framework
GoogleMaps.framework
GoogleMapsCore.framework
GoogleMapsM4B.framework (Premium Plan customers only)
Accelerate.framework
CoreData.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
CoreLocation.framework
CoreText.framework
GLKit.framework
ImageIO.framework
libc++.tbd
libz.tbd
OpenGLES.framework
QuartzCore.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
UIKit.framework
```

Now [Get the API key](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_ios_backend&reusekey=true)

Now you need to add following things in Plist

[image]

AppDelegate.m

```
@import GoogleMaps;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR API KEY"];
   return YES;
}
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate,GMSMapViewDelegate>{
    CLLocation *currentLocation;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewMarker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GMSMapView *mapView;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize viewMarker,locationManager,
@synthesize mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] == NO){
        NSLog(@"Your location service is not enabled, So go to Settings > Location Services");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Your location service is enabled");
    }
    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
       [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate method
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{
    currentLocation = [locations lastObject];
    if (currentLocation != nil){
        NSLog(@"The latitude value is - %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]);
        NSLog(@"The logitude value is - %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]);
    }
    //Current
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude zoom:13];

    self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.mapView.frame = viewMarker.bounds;
    [viewMarker addSubview:self.mapView];

    GMSMarker *marker1 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    //Current
    marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    marker1.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"boss-icon.png"];
    marker1.map = self.spyMapView;

    NSArray *arrLatLongValue = @[
                                 @{
                                     @"Latitude":@"12.9003",
                                     @"Longitude":@"80.2278"
                                     },
                                 @{
                                     @"Latitude":@"12.8447",
                                     @"Longitude":@"80.2254"
                                     },
                                 @{
                                     @"Latitude":@"12.7726",
                                     @"Longitude":@"80.2488"
                                     },
                                 @{
                                     @"Latitude":@"12.9171",
                                     @"Longitude":@"80.1923"
                                     }
                                 ];

    NSString *strWayPoints = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"via:%f,%f", [arrLatLongValue[0][@"Latitude"] doubleValue], [arrLatLongValue[0][@"Longitude"] doubleValue]];
    for(int j=0;j<arrLatLongValue.count;j++){
        CLLocationCoordinate2D position = { [[arrLatLongValue[j] objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue], [[arrLatLongValue[j] objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue] };
        GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
        marker.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Marker %i", j];
        marker.appearAnimation = YES;
        marker.flat = YES;
        if(j < 2)
            marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        else if(j >= 2 && j < 4)
            marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
        else
            marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

        if(j > 0)
            strWayPoints = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|via:%f,%f", strWayPoints, [arrLatLongValue[j][@"Latitude"] doubleValue], [arrLatLongValue[j][@"Longitude"] doubleValue]];

        marker.map = self.mapView;
    }
    //Current
    NSString *originString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];


    NSString *destinationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", @(12.9220085).doubleValue, @(80.0954032).doubleValue]; 

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&waypoints=%@&key=YOUR API KEY",originString,destinationString,strWayPoints];
    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(data == nil) {
            return;
        }else{
            NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSArray* latestRoutes = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];
            NSString *points=[[[latestRoutes objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"];
            @try {
                // TODO: better parsing. Regular expression?
                NSArray *temp= [self decodePolyLine:[points mutableCopy]];
                GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
                for(int idx = 0; idx < [temp count]; idx++){
                    CLLocation *location=[temp objectAtIndex:idx];
                    [path addCoordinate:location.coordinate];
                }
                // create the polyline based on the array of points.
                GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
                rectangle.strokeWidth=5.0;
                rectangle.map = self.spyMapView;
                [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
            }
            @catch (NSException * e) {
                // TODO: show erro
            }
        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
    }
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

## pragma mark - Drawing Lines

```
-(NSMutableArray *)decodePolyLine: (NSMutableString *)encoded {
    [encoded replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"
                                options:NSLiteralSearch
                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [encoded length])];
    NSInteger len = [encoded length];
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
    NSInteger lat=0;
    NSInteger lng=0;
    while (index < len) {
        NSInteger b;
        NSInteger shift = 0;
        NSInteger result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlat = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;
        NSNumber *latitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5] ;
        NSNumber *longitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5] ;
        printf("[%f,", [latitude doubleValue]);
        printf("%f]", [longitude doubleValue]);
        CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]] ;
        [array addObject:loc];
    }

    return array;
}
```