# Start navigation with multiple destinations on ios using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, url-scheme

The following code does not open the Google Maps app on an iPhone with navigation from one point to another, but when I copy the same URL one a desktop browser, it opens the google map.

How to start navigation in the google maps app?

> str = https://maps.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=18.606791,73.785611&destination=18.611997,73.971692&waypoints=18.606791,73.785611|18.611997,73.971692|18.465518,74.012204

```
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]])
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
}
```

Comment: Yuvaraj Kale Can you show your code and how do you apply?

Comment: Go through this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392092/google-maps-directions-url-error-when-adding-multiple-waypoints/41449231#41449231

Answer (score 0):

You can start with google documentation on available URL schemes. Specifically, there's a section on how to [add navigation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme#add_navigation_to_your_app) to your app.

Comment: I already gone through the documentation i am not getting any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
NSString *escapedString = [strUrl stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
    strUrl=[escapedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@"+"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
         [NSURL URLWithString:[@"comgooglemaps://?" stringByAppendingString:strUrl]]];
    }
```

Comment: No it only open google map but not showing the location i entered.