# I want to draw multi polygons on google map

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, geofencing, polygons

And is there any chance to select a polygon from  multi-polygons are present on google maps to modify that selected one only, I am using didTapAtCoordinates func to get Coordinates of that positions and storing in an array, Using that Array i created a GMSPath and then drawn a polygon  in ios objective-c

[image: Check The Image]

Check the image, i want draw one more

Comment: This asnwer helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392092/google-maps-directions-url-error-when-adding-multiple-waypoints/41449231#41449231

Comment: Please provide additional code, so we can easier understand, what you have tried so far

Comment: Check This link .  https://github.com/BRNMADHU/Map .

Comment: @Lepidopteron check the link .  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46786189/7961260

Comment: Simply i want to draw multiple polygons, is there any chance to select a polygon(geoArea)  to edit

Comment: hi @Singammadhukar how you calculate area and perimeter?